# can i join the threads that a ThreadPoolExecutor creates

Tags: java, multithreading, join, pool

I'm using ThreadPoolExecutor to make it easy to create threads to handle requests but now a requirement is to execute the requests in order. I was wondering if i can use the join method to make a thread get executed right after a previous launched thread finishes.

i've been looking at the api but i haven't found a method that returns the Thread object from the ThreadPoolExecutor

Can i do that? or do i need to implement something like my own thread factory to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want the requests to happen concurrently, you can use `java.util.concurrent.Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` and they'll happen one at a time.